# VoiceOver on macOS - stuck in browsers

Tags: voiceover, screen-readers

I use VO (Voice Over) to help me test accessibility on websites.

Recently VO started ignoring (not following) the keyboard navigation `Tab` and cursor clicks when navigating on Chrome or Firefox. Only shortcuts using `VO (ctrl + option) + *` work.

I noticed that when VO announces something in Chrome it always finishes by saying *"Chrome has a new window."* I don't remember that happening before.

I tried both browsers in incognito and the same problem happens. It works fine on Safari though.

Everything else works fine on macOS: any system application or any other installed app.

I didn't customize any VoiceOver settings, only the voice speed (to be faster). I suspect this started happening after I updated to macOS Mojave, but I'm not sure. But I know for sure this didn't happen when I had High Sierra installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue: There was some Chrome extensions messing up with VoiceOver.

After I uninstalled them and restart the browser it started working fine again.

---

Update: The problem is back, I couldn't yet find what's the reason. But now, if I shut down Chrome and open it again, VO works fine. I still believe it's caused by an extension that runs for too long, but I don't know which one. I can't tell which one because there are too many (+20).

Update 2: I've updated to macOS Catalina and never had the problem again. The extensions are exactly the same as before (probably with minor updates).

Comment: Which extensions? How specifically were they messing up VoiceOver?

Comment: Hi @ScottSchupbach. Actually the problem is showing up again. I've updated the answer to reflect my current status.